# How to fix foundation on bedrock leaking water?

Tags: water, wood, foundation

I have bought a 1969 house on a bedrock hill, it's laying on a 12" large concrete foundation, the deepest part of the crawl space is 4' tall and the smallest a couple of inches. On the shortest part of the crawl space, the water is leaking and it made everything rot.

In the crawl space, the bedrock is uneven and there is small ponds of water when it is raining. So it is difficult to drain.

The wooden structure is sitting directly on the concrete. There is no sill plate. The floor joists seem to hold the walls and where there was water issues, the rim joist are all rotten. [image]

Outside, where there was the water problem, the granite bedrock arrive almost at level with the foundation, so it's difficult to drain as well. I tought of creating a trench around the perimeter to drain the water away, but granite is hard to break and I don't have the budget for dynamites.

Whats the best way to fix my problem? Should I encapsulate and don't deal with the water? Pour a concrete slab? dynamite the bedrock outside to create a drain?[image]

Comment: A local excavating company will probably have a jack hammer attachment for their machine, or a local tool rental will have jack hammers for rent, so you can do the work yourself.  Before doing anything find where the water is coming from, then work from there.  Do not guess.

Comment: So what is your question?  How to cut the bedrock to drain?

Comment: Whats the best way to fix my problem? Should I encapsulate and don't deal with the water? Poor a concrete slab? dynamite the bedrock outside to create a drain?

Comment: Diamond saws are **very useful** for cutting channels for water without having to dynamite anything. Someone evidently took a dead easy foundation and screwed it up big time by stupid detailing. I think I'd start with opening a drain hole at the low point and pressure-washing all the grot out of there. Once you have **clean** bedrock, the next steps become easier to see.

Comment: "Best" is asking for opinions, and opinion-based questions are off-topic here. Are you looking for the long-term solution, or the cheapest, or one you can do yourself, or...? Where in the world are you? What is it, exactly, that we're looking at in this picture?

Comment: I am searching for a long term solution that won't break the bank but will fix my problem forever, I am in the Canada, Quebec, Laurentide. We see the shallow part inside the crawl space, I have removed the rotten floor joists.

Comment: I would encourage drainage slots being cut encapsulated areas can leak and hold water from your question the bedrock is even with the foundation so cutting a trench outside to channel water away from the building would be my choice. Blasting could have worked before the building was set but not now.  I was thinking of a commercial grade saw but even a mid size on a chainsaw with a “diamond” blade and water could be used to trench and get the water below the foundation level , drain all of the pools and rebuild. The chainsaw ~18-24” blade can be rented make sure to keep wet real wet $$$ blades

Comment: I still don't understand the picture.  What is all that rubble and black soil we see?  Where exactly is the crawl space in the picture?  Did you pull out the floor that was there?  // Tough question: did you have it inspected?  Do you have disclosure requirements in Canada, as we have in the US?  Was the problem disclosed? / Is there a sump pail and sump pump in the taller part of the crawl space?  What's the shape of the ground around the house?  Do you live on a slope, or on the flat?  Describe the water flow outside the house, please.

Comment: The black ruble is the crawl space, I removed the floor and the floor joists. I did make it inspected, but the inspector said it wasn't all that bad and I got a pretty good deal knowing I might have to destroy it. We installed french drain, a sump pail and sump pump in the tallest part of the crawl space that part is working well. There is a slope, but water like holes and the bedrock is full of small cavities everywhere making it difficult or impossible to drain at this side of the house. I will post some more pictures.